# Qlabel translated in Turkish: some character missing. How to solve?

Tags: qt, qlabel

In my Qt application for an embedded system based on a ARM9 Single Board Computer, I have to use some labels that can change according to the language choose from user. I noted some words appear incomplete depending on the used font: for example, if I use "arial.ttf" all is ok, but if I set "Eurostile.ttf", some characters are missing ("BİPOLAR KESİM" becomes "B POLAR KES M").
All labels are inserted as
 QString::fromUtf8("myTurkishLabel")
Any solution?

Comment: Does the font have the corresponding letters at all? If it works with Arial it's probably not an encoding issue

Comment: When I debug my program, I can see all turkish characters, also in a font different from Arial.ttf. When I upload in my embedded system, some characters aren't correctly visible

Comment: Are you sure the font file you have on the dev pc and the one on the embedded are the same?

Comment: Add more information on the embedded system, which OS, which Qt version, if freetype and/or fontconfig are used etc. Also, are you displaying the string with widgets or QtQuick?

Comment: SBC Variscite OMAP SOM-OM 35, Linux-based, Qt 4.8.6.
Program developped with QtCreator